# ¿Cómo obtener documentos en un rango de fechas con mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

estoy intentando obtener las fechas en un intervalo establecido como intento abajo:

```
{fechaRealizacion: {$and: [{$gte: new Date('2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z') }, {$lte: new Date('2020-03-10T13:33:35.835Z') }]}}
```

MongoDB Compass no me lo detecta como un filtro a diferencia de:

```
{fechaRealizacion: {$gte: new Date('2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')}}
```

¿Es porque la expresión `$and` devuelve un booleano? Si es así, ¿cómo podría obtener los documentos en el rango establecido por `$gte` y `$lte`?

En mi log de la API me aparece esto:

> MongooseError [CastError]: 
>   Cast to date failed for value "{
>   andForRange: { '$and': [ [Object], [Object] ] } }" at path
>   "fechaRealizacion" for model "test"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí, el operador `and` es un booleano y MongoDB no puede comparar con un campo de otro tipo, para obtener el intervalo usando el operador `and` este tiene que ir antes de la comparación del campo, algo así:

```
{$and: [{fechaRealizacion: {$gte: new Date('2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')} }, {fechaRealizacion: {$lte: new Date('2020-03-10T13:33:35.835Z')} }] }
```

O mucho mejor, obviar el operador `and` y agregar las condiciones como parte del comparador:

```
{fechaRealizacion: { $gte: new Date('2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'), $lte: new Date('2020-03-10T13:33:35.835Z') } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto me funcionó:

```
{fechaRealizacion: {$gte: new Date('2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'), $lte: new Date('2020-03-10T13:33:35.835Z')}}
```

Fuente: http://rafinguer.blogspot.com/2014/10/fechas-en-mongodb.html

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente query si funciona compartido en el post anterior:

{fechaRealizacion: {$gte: new Date('2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'), $lte: new Date('2020-03-10T13:33:35.835Z')}}

Y si quieren todas las transacción de un día y de una hora en particular pueden ocupar la siguiente búsqueda:

```
{createdAt: {$gt: new Date('2023-08-22T21:25:00.000Z')}}
```

este mostrara todas las transacciones mayores a esa hora.